# Multiple Components Using One Store

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

What's the best way to handle a case where multiple components are using one store (which is populated by API calls in an action creator), but each component may need to access different sets of data without effecting the other. I.e.: two table components display data from the `WidgetStore`; one table wants all widgets, the other only displays widgets whose name contains "foo" (this would be based on user input). The table being queried via the API has tens of thousands of widgets, so loading them all into the store and filtering from the store isn't practical. Is there a Flux architecture (like Redux) that already has a way of handling this type of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to just create a parent component and selectively hand off data, using a pluck or selector function, to each of the children.

For the more general answer for yourself going forward... if you follow something along the lines like redux there is already proven patterns which will help you understand passing complex data down.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Can you flesh out (or point me to an article) about how the parent component selectively handing off data would work in my use case?

Comment: For any other readers, the following three links help flesh out what @mattclemens suggests above. Thanks again for pointing me in this direction. [Container and Presentational Components by Dan Abramov](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0), [chantastic's gist on container components](https://gist.github.com/chantastic/fc9e3853464dffdb1e3c), and [Jason Bonta's talk at React.js Conf 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYzlpRvWZ6c&t=1351).